# How to use multiple facebook share button?

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-sharer

well i have an application that loads various rows of the product with item title and item description and item image. All i want to do is attach a button which allow user to share that particular product, with that particular title, description and image thumbnail. We will have several rows of products and each should have share button to share respective item title, description and image. How can this be achieved? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](http://www.hs.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150211527410844). Hope it works.